# Data structure for keeping 3000 value

Tags: algorithm

I want to save 3000 int value in a arraylist . Then I want to retrieve 5 smallest integer . What data structure is appropriate for this ?

Note that, I have used Arraylist data structure . The position of item in list is significant . After sorting , the position is altered . How can I fulfill my purpose ?

Comment: You've got to give more context. The answer could be a sorted array, heap (minimal or maximal!) tree, or a lot of other things -depends on the actual problem at hand.

Comment: What language? As written now, this post is probably off-topic for SO.

Comment: This question is way too general. What language are you using? What other operations would you like your data-structure to support (insertion, extraction, etc)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming that Java is your language of choice:**

If you know all values in advanced, and you're not planning to add new values or remove existing ones, then you can use an array:

```
int[] array = new int[3000]; // or simply int[] array = {your values};
array[0] = ...
array[1] = ...
...
Arrays.sort(array);
```

Otherwise, you can use a list:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(...);
list.add(...);
...
Collections.sort(list);
```

Comment: Collections.sort(**set**)? It hurts me to see it. In addition, there are much more efficient ways to find top5 then sorting. I really dislike this answer.

Comment: Yeah, kinda guessed that on `Set` to be honest... should have verified really... thanks for the tip; answer revised.

Comment: @Amit , can you plz suggest me that efficient ways ?